# Quickblox - Listener Firing Multiple times

Tags: parse-platform, listener, chat, session-timeout, quickblox

I'm using Quickblox in Ionic (Angular), with Parse for my database. Whenever I send friend requests, it only sends one, and the receiver only receives one, but the listener goes off some random number of times (3-10), Consequently, if I send a chat, it will send the same number as there are friend requests. However, if I hard-code in the user who sends and receives chats, it the chat receiver still does the same thing.

I'm using Parse to manage Quickblox accounts. So I'm fairly theres some issue with session management and connections to Quickblox.